# Responsive CSS: divs not responding on alternate resolution

Tags: css

Everything is working perfectly except when the browser/viewport contracts to 1280px the 3 divs in the body all break. When the browser contracts, I only want the #related div to break and the other 2 divs (#main, #images) to float side by side with #images stretching to fill the screen. If you add a fixed width to #images div on the contracted CSS, everything stacks perfectly, but I don't want the #images div to have a fixed width, I want it to stretch out to fill the screen.

Thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            }
        header nav {
            float:left;
            }
        header nav ul {
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
            }
        #menu1 li {
            list-style-type:none;
            float:left;
            margin:0;
            width:200px;
            height:50px;
            background:orange;
            margin-right:1px;
            }
        #bodywrapper {
            clear:both;
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            }
        #images {
            position:relative;
            margin:0 300px 0 600px;
            background:cyan;
            }
        #main {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:600px;
            background:lime;
            }
        #related {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            width:300px;
            background:red;
            }
        #wrapper {
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1280px){
            #bodywrapper {
                clear:both;
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                }
            #images {
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                margin:0;
                background:cyan;
                }
            #main {
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                margin:0;
                width:600px;
                background:lime;
                }
            #related {
                clear:both;
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                margin:0;
                width:100%;
                background:purple;
                }
            #wrapper {
                width:100%;
                height:auto;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                }
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu1">
                <li><a href="">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="bodywrapper">
        <div id="main">
            111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
        </div>
        <div id="images">
            222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222
        </div>
        <div id="related">
            333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both the main and images to a percentage value and the images to float to the right.

```
 #main {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            margin:0;
            width:40%;
            background:lime;
            }
 #images {
            float:right;
            position:relative;
            width: 60%;
            margin:0;
            background:cyan;
            }
```

If you want to keep the main column to have a fixed width then try this: wrap a div around the 2 columns (main and images) with a class of container and then put the following css for under 1280px.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.main {
    width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.images {
    margin-left: 600px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pete_D/bBQnM/2/

Comment: @Joebone Actually I set it to 60% to cover all the page. He said he didnt want to put a fixed with to the images.

Comment: Also true, Pete! I suppose that's why my answer was more of a question, as the end effect is different - based on his original example I assumed he wanted to keep the first div with a fixed width of 600px. While I actually prefer your layout, it may or may not be what he wanted, hence both answers :)

Comment: **Your second option worked perfectly, thanks @peter!** Just to clarify, the @media tag doesn't seem to completely override the original CSS, right? Because with my original script (the one that didn't work), if I removed the original CSS and just used the css1280 by default everything worked perfectly. But as soon as the 1280css was the secondary style sheet it didn't work. Why would that be?

Comment: The media tag execute and therefore override which ever styles you put in there when the condition is met. So if you have for a column a margin-left: 50px; for over 1280px and you have a @media tag for less then 1280px which in it states that the margin-left: 0px for the same column, that will override the first case only if the screen size is under 1280px.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the floats are just confusing the effect? if you replace the max width block with the following (removing the right margin when the "3" div is wrapped), is it the effect you are looking for? You specifically mentioned not giving #images a width, so the solution below with 60% width I assume is not what you are looking for...

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 1280px){
        #images {
        margin-right:0;
        background:cyan;
        }
        #related {
            position:relative;
            margin:0;
            width: 100%;
            background:purple;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @media rule to clear:left the 3rd div item on particular window width setting is the basic / easiest solution.